# Reverse a N-N mapping of data in Dhall

Tags: dhall

Given is a config of apps and containers with an app being able to have multiple containers a container being able to have multiple apps. I want to be able to output them in 2 ways

- Per app list the containers
- Per container list the apps

The data format is simple, but I can't seem to find a way to get both of these representations without repeating the relation.

Example data when starting from containers having apps

```
let app1 = { name = "app1" }
let app2 = { name = "app2" }

let containers = [
  { name = "container1", apps = [ app1 ] },
  { name = "container2", apps = [ app1, app2 ] }
]

{- I can easily transform this data to the following -}

[
  { app = "app1", container = "container1" },
  { app = "app1", container = "container2" },
  { app = "app2", container = "container2" }
]

{- But I cannot seem to get it into the requested format -}
[
  "app1" = [ "container1", "container2" ]
  "app2" = [ "container2" ]
]
```

I think using identifiers as `Text` cannot work as there is no way to merge associated lists or something alike using equal identifiers.

Using records I can merge something like this `{a1 = {c1 = True}} /\ {a1 = {c2 = True}} /\ {a2 = {c2 = True}}`. Which would be `{a1 = {c1 = True, c2 = True}, a2 = {c2 = True}}`.
But I can't get to this state in the first place because I can't 'reverse' records.

I don't care how I need to structure the config as long as I don't need to repeat the relation twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it's not possible to do exactly what you're requesting because the language does not permit `Text` comparisons

The closest solution I can think of is something like this:

```
let Map = https://prelude.dhall-lang.org/v21.1.0/Map/Type.dhall

let List/concatMap = https://prelude.dhall-lang.org/v21.1.0/List/concatMap.dhall

let List/map = https://prelude.dhall-lang.org/v21.1.0/List/map.dhall

let startingMapping
    : Map Text (Map Text {})
    = toMap
        { container1 = toMap { app1 = {=} }
        , container2 = toMap { app1 = {=}, app2 = {=} }
        }

let desiredMapping
    : Map Text (Map Text {})
    = toMap
        { app1 = toMap { container1 = {=}, container2 = {=} }
        , app2 = toMap { container2 = {=} }
        }

let transpose
    : ∀(a : Type) → Map Text (Map Text a) → Map Text (Map Text a)
    = λ(a : Type) →
        List/concatMap
          { mapKey : Text, mapValue : Map Text a }
          { mapKey : Text, mapValue : Map Text a }
          ( λ(x : { mapKey : Text, mapValue : Map Text a }) →
              List/map
                { mapKey : Text, mapValue : a }
                { mapKey : Text, mapValue : Map Text a }
                ( λ(y : { mapKey : Text, mapValue : a }) →
                    { mapKey = y.mapKey
                    , mapValue =
                      [ { mapKey = x.mapKey, mapValue = y.mapValue } ]
                    }
                )
                x.mapValue
          )

in  assert : transpose {} startingMapping ≡ desiredMapping
```

The assertion fails, though, with this error message:

```
Error: Assertion failed

[ - { mapKey = "app1"
    , mapValue = [ { mapKey = "container1", mapValue = {=} } ]
    }
, - { mapKey = "app1"
    , mapValue = [ { mapKey = "container2", mapValue = {=} } ]
    }
, + { mapKey = "app1"
    , mapValue =
      [ { mapKey = "container1", mapValue = {=} }
      , { mapKey = "container2", mapValue = {=} }
      ]
    }
, …
]


41│     assert : transpose {} startingMapping ≡ desiredMapping
```

… because the result does not consolidate the two duplicate `app1` keys like you were requesting.

Comment: Is this maybe possible by converting a record to a Map, then revert the structure, then convert back into a map and then merge them? Is it possible to convert a Map to a structure? The type of this conversion could be known because we have the type of the initial record data.

Comment: @alazeo: It's not possible to convert a `Map` into a record, but there is a discussion about adding such a feature: https://github.com/dhall-lang/dhall-lang/issues/979